# Bootstrap SASS 5-column grid responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, sass

I made an additional col-x-5th column with 20% width:

```
.col-xl-5th {
  @include make-xl-column(2.4)
}
.col-lg-5th{
  @include make-lg-column(2.4)
}
.col-md-5th{
  @include make-md-column(2.4)
}
.col-sm-5th{
  @include make-sm-column(2.4)
}
.col-xs-5th {
  @include make-xs-column(2.4)
}
```

Pretty simple stuff. My problem lies in trying to make a responsive layout using this. Putting classes like these on an element:

```
col-xs-5th col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2
```

Causes the col-xs-5th to completely overwrite everything on any viewpoint (if I check it out in chrome code inspection, the xs viewport is the first priority wise, the correct one is right after it). I'm pretty sure this is caused because I'm importing the sass file after everything else,  however if I import it prior to the grid system, it just gets ignored as everything else will overwrite the col-xs-5th column instead.

Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: Is `make-xl-column()` a custom mixin?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create your own custom breakpoints and with Bootstrap, it's not as simple as you'd think with your example. In order to this, you'd have to use Bootstrap to generate things properly. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140709143212/http://www.gizra.com/content/custom-breakpoint-bootstrap-sass/) explains how to create your custom breakpoint and check out the [example GitHub repo](https://github.com/Gizra/custom-breakpoint-example).

Comment: That doesn't matter, like I said, if I use col-xs-5th, it still overwrites everything, including col-sm-4, col-md-3 and col-lg-3. My custom breakpoint works great, but it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: The reason `col-xs-5th` is causing issues is because it's added to the end of your stylesheet so it takes precedence over the bootstrap columns meaning all your bootstrap columns will be ignored and it's considered a stand alone class, not a column.

Comment: Did you read the article? It shows you how to properly make a new breakpoint, your method is incorrect. If you want cheat and use your method, you'd have to hard code the values like so: http://sassmeister.com/gist/1fee19496b5715747b57

Comment: @idiotstrike sorry I forgot to mention you before but take a look at my comments